# SQL Installation hanging on windows 10

Tags: sql-server, sql, sql-server-2008

I've tried installed *every* version of SQL Express I can get my hands on (And I've got the MSDN SQL 2016 CTP 2).

Everythings hangs, and always at this point.

I've a feeling its a .net related issue as Vs2010 also hangs.

**Tail end of Log**

```
(01) 2015-08-26 18:54:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\RefCount\sql_common_core13
(01) 2015-08-26 18:54:58 Slp: Sco: File 'D:\x64\setup\sql_common_core_msi\x64\sql_common_core.msi' does not exist
(01) 2015-08-26 18:54:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to create base registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, machine 
(01) 2015-08-26 18:54:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey 
(01) 2015-08-26 18:54:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0
(01) 2015-08-26 18:54:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get registry value InstallDir
(01) 2015-08-26 18:54:58 Slp: Sco: File 'D:\x64\setup\sql_common_core_msi\x64\sql_common_core.msi' does not exist
(01) 2015-08-26 18:54:58 Slp: Sco: File 'D:\x64\setup\sql_common_core_msi\x64\sql_common_core.msi' does not exist
(01) 2015-08-26 18:54:58 Slp: Checkpoint: PREINSTALL_SQL_COMMON_CORE_CPU64_ACTION
(01) 2015-08-26 18:54:58 Slp: Sco: Waiting for service 'msiserver' to accept the stop request.
(01) 2015-08-26 18:54:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open SC Manager
(01) 2015-08-26 18:54:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open service handle for service msiserver
(01) 2015-08-26 18:54:58 Slp: Invoking QueryServiceStatus Win32 API
(01) 2015-08-26 18:54:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to close service handle for service msiserver
(01) 2015-08-26 18:54:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to close SC Manager
(01) 2015-08-26 18:54:58 Slp: Target package: "D:\x64\setup\sql_common_core_msi\sql_common_core.msi"
```

Thoughts?

[image: Hanging out...]

Comment: There should be a log file generated, we sort of need that, to understand what is going on.

Comment: Updated - I suspect its the missing file bit - but its from an ISO? And every copy of different ISOs (MSDN) I download produces the same.

Answer (score 9):

I had this issue with SQL Server 2019. The key part of this is:

> Sco: Waiting for service 'msiserver' to accept the stop request.

I managed to force it to stop by running in an eleveated powershell window

```
taskkill /f /fi "imagename eq msiexec.exe"
```

This then enabled the installer to continue to the next part of the installation.

Comment: I also encountered an issue installing 2019, where the installer got stuck on "Installing Setup Files".  Looking at the logs in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Setup Bootstrap\Log\<date>\Detail.txt` I noticed it repeated "Attempting to close service handle for service msiserver".  The above `taskkill` command solved my issue, the installer proceeded automatically.

Comment: Also observed this issue when installing patches for both 2014 and 2019, not sure why.  But running this command also helped in those scenarios as well.

Comment: I too was geting the hang at 'Installing Setup Files' when installing SQL 2019, launched within my own MSI project.  Apparently, this was a known issue (see [KB2820068](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb2820068-can-t-install-sql-server-by-using-installshield-or-bootstrapping-application-1fb621ed-926f-484d-36c1-589014ea2fa7)), fixed by including an extra parameter `/SkipInstallerRunCheck` on the launching command line.